# Write a program that prints out every line of input exactly as they were entered

Tags: java

Non-CS major here taking my first programming class for fun. As the title states, my first assignment is "Write a program that prints out every line of input exactly as they were entered." My program right now will accept one input, but not any others. How can I fix this? Thank you so much :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class echohw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ans;
        ans = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print(ans);
```

Comment: try adding a `while` loop

Comment: Out of curiosity: in the class you are taking, did nobody mention the concept of loops to you? And hint: if you keep delegating your questions to others like this, you will maybe finish your assignments, but you will most likely not learn the things it takes to *be* a programmer. Which means that you will probably fail any exam where you can't delegate the heavy lifting to others.

Comment: No, we haven't gone over loops yet.

Answer (score 2):

Like [Scary Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat) said, use a [`while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class echohw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ans;
        // Continue printing user input unless "stop" is entered
        while (!(ans = in.nextLine()).equals("stop"))
            System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use array function to store multiple user inputs. In this example, I try to make it simple so you can understand it well. If you have any other doubt, you can ask me here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class echohw {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Decide number of inputs
        System.out.println("How many inputs you want to enter: ");
        int numInput = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

        //Store inputs
        String aryInput[] = new String[numInput];
        for (int i = 0; i < aryInput.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the input " + (i+1) + " : ");
                aryInput[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }

        //Print inputs
        for (int i = 0; i < aryInput.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Input " + (i+1) + " : ");
                System.out.println(aryInput[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why bother storing the values?

Comment: Since @kjar48 is kinda new to programming, why not just give him/her some more simple codes to let him/her understand the programming flow?

Comment: Since @kjar48 is kinda new to programming, why not just give her the simplest code to achieve her requirements